# build dictionary for which value is average length of word

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Here are the requirements:

Write a function that accepts a dictionary where the key is a letter and the
value is a list of words that begin with that letter and returns a dictionary where the key is a letter and the value is
the average length of the words in the list

For example, if `word_dictionary={"a":['am','apple','along','alive'],"b":['big','believe','beef']}`, the outcome should be `{"a":4.25, "b"=4.6666667}`

Here are what I have done right now:

```
word_dictionary={"a":['am','apple','along','alive'],"b":['big','believe','beef']}
def average_word(word_dictionary):
    for lis in word_dictionary.values():
        length=0
        ave=0
        for word in lis:
            length+=len(word)
            ave=float(len(word))/len(lis)
            print(ave)
```

Unfortunately, my outcome is not a dictionary but a list of numbers like this:

```
0.5
1.25
1.25
1.25
1.0
2.3333333333333335
1.3333333333333333
```

Can anybody help with it?

Comment: the values seem off: I get `{'a': 4.25, 'b': 4.666666666666667}`

Comment: You need to store your output in a new dictionary, so declare one at the top of your function. Then store the final value of `ave` in this new dictionary for each key. Finally return the dictionary with the averages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a list of numbers out because that's what you're asking for with the line: `print(ave)`.

It prints all of those different numbers because you placed your print statement inside your two loops.

Really you want something like:

```
word_dictionary={"a":['am','apple','along','alive'],"b":['big','believe','beef']}

def average_word(word_dictionary):
    average_length_dictionary = {}
    for letter, words in word_dictionary.items():
        length = 0
        for word in words:
            length += len(word)
        average_length_dictionary[letter] = length/len(words)
    return average_length_dictionary
```

By doing this, you create a new dictionary which you can fill with your new keys (the letters) and their corresponding values (the average length).

Comment: why declare `average_length_dictionary` outside of your function?

Comment: @pault I lied about writing a loop version. This answer seems to do that very wel, and explained it properly. Le me edit it according to your good remark

Comment: @Egomatic: you didn"t explain why OP results were wrong (even if you fixed the issue)

Answer (score 1):

You get the wrong values because this formula is wrong:

```
ave=float(len(word))/len(lis)
```

should probably use the sum computed the line above. So:

```
ave=float(length)/len(lis)
```

So you don't need to compute that at each iteration. Well, that should fix it.

Now, for the more "pythonic" solution, I would do with a dictionary comprehension, and the usual `sum / len` using a comprehension for `sum`

```
word_dictionary={"a":['am','apple','along','alive'],"b":['big','believe','beef']}

result = {k:(sum(len(x) for x in v)/len(v)) for k,v in word_dictionary.items()}
```

and my result is correct (yours seem a little off):

```
{'a': 4.25, 'b': 4.666666666666667}
```

Comment: I *would* do it this way too, but this is almost certainly homework and I doubt OP's teacher is going to expect this as the answer.

Comment: Why do you always seem to `sum` up things faster than I do, especially when it comes to `sum`.  :D

Comment: Or... `{k: statistics.mean(map(len, v)) for k, v in word_dictionary.items()}`?

Comment: @pault don't make me write a loop version. Okay I'm doing it :)

Comment: @JonClements now with that OP gets busted for sure

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way..

Your averages should be 4.25, and 4.66667. 5 letters in 3 words in the a list, and 2 letters in the other word, (5 + 5 + 5 + 2)/4 = 4.25

You want to initialize an empty dictionary at the top, and then iterate through `word_dictionary.items()` which iterates through both the key and the items in your dictionary. For the items piece, `lis`, you create an empty list outside of the inner loop, and append the length of each word, once it finishes, it takes the avg of the word lengths, and lastly creates a new entry in the dictionary where the key (your 'a', 'b' values from the word_dictionary) = the average.

```
def get_word_length_dict(some_dictionary):
    new_word_dictionary = {}        
    for key, lis in some_dictionary.items():
        word_values = []
        for word in lis:
            word_values.append(len(word))
        avg = np.array(word_values).mean()
        new_word_dictionary[key] = avg
        return new_word_dictionary

get_word_length_dict(word_dictionary)
```